# How set application label in maven by properties?

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I build my apk file by maven.
But I want change application label and I can't do it :(

I found manifest-update parameter [manifestApplicationLabel](http://jayway.github.io/maven-android-plugin/manifest-update-mojo.html#manifestApplicationLabel), but don't understand how use it?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with android development, nur the plugin. But this seems pretty straightforward.

Add this section to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>update-manifest</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>manifest-update</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <manifest>
            <applicationLabel>YOUR_APP_LABEL</applicationLabel>               
          </manifest>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```